# Cannot Uninstall Python 3.11 in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.11

I want to clean unintsall python in my machine, however the uninstaller prompt of Python displays an error :

```
# **Setup Failed**
One or more issues cause the setup to fail. Please fix the issues and then retry the setup. For more information see the log file.

0x80070643- Fatal Error during Installation
```

What issues is python refering to that must be resolved before I try the setup? The launcher uninstalled without any problems, however Python Interpreter is not uninstalling. My python directory did not have Script folder too, where I could've used `pip uninstall package_name` command.

I tried deleteing the Python folder in `\AppData\Programs`, but it still isn't deleting.I used Numpy and Sci-Kit packages in Pycharm, so I deleted Pycharm too however, it's still not uninstalling.

Answer (score 1):

Run CMD as administrators, then go to the following directory:

```
C:\Users\{Your User Name}\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{c6a7d2cb-61ea-4f5e-bc56-95faa938bacf}
```

Then Type the following:

```
python-3.11.3-amd64.exe /uninstall
```

your installed version maybe different so you have to change it to the installed version.

Then press **Enter**

Comment: that was only working solution on this stupid OS for me, thanks

Comment: The question was about the Windows OS, so I answered according to that.